# LaTeX code formatting using lstlistings: custom keywords not recognized

Tags: listings, keywords

I'm trying to add some keywords to an existing language using the `morekeywords` setting:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.98}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\lstset {
  language=xml,
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  keywordstyle={\bfseries\color{Blue}},
  commentstyle={\color{Red}\textit},
  stringstyle=\color{Magenta},
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=4,
  morekeywords={rdf,rdfs,owl}  % <-- adding custom keywords
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Band">
  <owl :Class rdf :ID="Band">
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

gives me

[image]

When there is trailing colon, the keywords `owl` and `rdf` are not recognized. However, there is no problem with built-in keywords (C example):

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: I don't think `while` is a built-in keyword for the XML language.

Comment: @egreg The second example is from C for illustration.

Comment: There is a big difference. In the XML language, `listings` declares `:` as a letter, which it doesn't for the C language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colon is the namespace indicator in `XML` so this behavior is not really wrong! If you open this xml in gedit you will see that GTK syntax highlighter does exactly the same!:

[image]

But you can do a little hack! If you add `:` as delimiter, you can achieve what you want. Please note that I'm neither a listings nor xml expert so I'm not sure this is the best solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.98,0.98,0.98}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\lstset {
  language=xml,
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  keywordstyle={\bfseries\color{Blue}},
  commentstyle={\color{Red}\textit},
  stringstyle=\color{Magenta},
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=4,
  morekeywords={rdf,rdfs,owl},
  moredelim=*[s][\ttfamily]{:}{:} %Newly added line
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Band">
  <owl :Class rdf :ID="Band">
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Which generates this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it fails to recognize `rdf`.

Comment: Yes. I didn't pay attention. I will try to modify it...

Comment: @Yang I modified the answer. Now rdf is also detected. As you can see ID is highlighted but as I said I'm not xml expert so I don't know if this behavior is fine or not.

Comment: Yes, `ID` is not highlighted on my machine. Thanks!